# ProcessInstance fields not visible

Tags: processinstancenode

I have created a report type on 'Process Instance' object, in which I have fields,'Submitted Date', 'Record Name', 'Approved Date'.

But while querying processInstance object from the workbench, I am not able to see 'Submitted Date' and record name.
How can I find these two fields? any help??

Answer (score 0):

May be you would want to query from ProcessSteps Object

```
SELECT id,(Select ActorId,Comments,CreatedById,CreatedDate,Id,StepStatus,SystemModstamp,TargetObjectId FROM ProcessSteps where stepstatus = 'Started') FROM CustomObject__c
```

CreatedDate refers to Submitted date.

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008xcQIAQ)